# Column getting pushed down page during animation

Tags: jquery, css

I have 3 divs, all originally with widths of 33.333%. When a div is clicked, I would like the div to expand to 80%, and the other two unselected divs to collapse to 10%. I also would like this process to be animated. When I try, the rightmost column gets pushed down the page until the animation has finished. How can I get this process to be fluent?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <title>
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="column" id="column1">    
            1
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="column2">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="column3">
            3
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
body {
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px
}
.column {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
#column1{
    width:33.33333%;
    background:red;
}
#column2{
    width:33.33333%;
    background:white;
}
#column3{
    width:33.33333%;
    background:blue;
}​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#column1").click(function(){
    $("#column1").animate({width:"80%"},{duration:1500,queue:false});
    $("#column2").animate({width:"10%"},{duration:1500,queue:false});
    $("#column3").animate({width:"10%"}, {duration:1500,queue:false});
  });
  $("#column2").click(function(){
    $("#column1").animate({width:"10%"},{duration:1500,queue:false});
    $("#column2").animate({width:"80%"},{duration:1500,queue:false});
    $("#column3").animate({width:"10%"}, {duration:1500,queue:false});
  });
  $("#column3").click(function(){
    $("#column1").animate({width:"10%"},{duration:1500,queue:false});
    $("#column2").animate({width:"10%"},{duration:1500,queue:false});
    $("#column3").animate({width:"80%"}, {duration:1500,queue:false});
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KkxHS/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedWidth = "80%";
    var othersWidth = "10%"
    $(".column").click(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        $(this).siblings().animate({
            width: "10%"
        }, 1500, function() {
            self.animate({
                width: "80%"
            }, {
                duration: 1500,
                queue: false
            });

        });
    });
});​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/atif089/KkxHS/3/

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".column").click(function() {
        var self = this;
        $(this).siblings().animate({
            width: "10%"
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            queue: false
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(self);
            $(self).animate({
                width: "80%"
            }, {
                duration: 1500,
                queue: false
            });
        }, 500);

    });
});​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/atif089/KkxHS/4/

Answer (score 0):

Atif, thank you very much for your response. In the time between my posting and your response, I located this thread, [jquery animation on floating elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377986/jquery-animation-on-floating-elements). I have followed this example which produced exactly what I was looking for.